# start nginx service on virtual interfaces

Tags: fedora, systemd, network-interface, nginx

`nginx.service` failed to start at boot because `eth0:0` is not yet configured : nginx is IP-based configured.

I have enabled `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` and added it in the unit wait section but it does not seem to be enough.

`eth0:0` is configured at boot like the rest of the local network.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Post your `nginx.service` file.

Comment: And, what do you mean by `eth0:0`? That looks like an obsolete interface alias, which you should never see on a Linux system from the last decade or so.

Comment: I have never used `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` nor `systemd-networkd.service`, but when I have a service that has an issue like this i use `After=network-online.target` in the service unit.

Comment: @GracefulRestart that was it ! Thanks. I found systemd-networkd-wait-online in the docs but I must have misunderstood its use. After=network-online.target works just fine : put it as an answer I will approve it. :)

Comment: @Michael Hampton eth0:0 is a virtual interface.

Comment: Really? How did you set that up?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/create-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-single-network-interface/ ;)

Comment: That's the obsolete method that you should not use anymore - and indeed not in over a decade. (And that site is infamous for bad tutorials.)   You should be doing [this](https://serverfault.com/a/461536/126632) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` unit requires that your network is managed by `systemd-networkd.service` and I do not remember that being setup in any of the recent distributions I use.

As per my comment, anytime I had a service running under systemd that tries to start before the network is ready, I just need to add `After=network-online.target` in the service unit to make sure the service waits until the network is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the nginx vHost to listen on the specific IP. Nginx doesn’t care about the interface, after all you listen on IP and of course ports. As long as your alias is set up and the IP is routed correctly then nginx can listen on it.

I hope that helps.

tl;dr nginx doesn’t care, it just wants to know which IP